# JavaFX KeyCodeCombination does not work on Mac

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem using key combinations on mac in JavaFX. Somehow it does not work and uses the key combinations only outside the java application. This is how I apply the accelerator to the menu item:

```
mainView.getMenuBar().getUndoItem().setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.LEFT, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN));
```

I also tried different combinations. I hope somebody can help me, thanks!